# ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid 00980. 00000 - "synonym translation is no longer valid"

Tags: oracle-ebs

We have a solution which works on Oracle EBS and it deals with users present in Oracle EBS suit and roles and responsibility associated with them. 
We used to fetch data from `FND_USER` and other related tables.

We have created one user which is having limited access and created one synonym to read data from FND_user table.
Synonym is created successfully but when we fetch data using: `Select * from FND_USER` logged in as the created user, we're getting the following error:

> ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid 
>   00980. 00000 -  "synonym translation is no longer valid"

Same permissions are given to a user in `12.2.4` version and it works fine.

Synonym is created using below command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM FND_USER for APPS.FND_USER;
```

We have created one user and assigned a role which contains different permissions as stated below

Administrator permissions 
1.Rights present on Oracle packages: 
Ans : Packages have Invoker rights.

```
create role ${new role};

create user ${new user} identified by ${password}; 

grant create session to ${new user}; 

grant create synonym to ${new user}; 

grant ${new role} to ${new user};
```

Grant permissions to the new role created in the above step (${new role}):

```
grant select on APPS.FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_USER to ${new role}; 

grant select on SYS.DBA_USERS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_RESPONSIBILITY_VL to ${new role};

grant select on APPS.FND_APPLICATION_VL to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_DATA_GROUPS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_ALL to ${new role}; 

grant select on DUAL to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.RA_CUSTOMERS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_MENUS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_REQUEST_GROUPS to ${new role};

grant select on APPS.FND_APPLICATION to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_DATA_GROUP_UNITS to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_APPLICATION_TL to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_RESPONSIBILITY to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.WF_ROLES to ${new role};

grant select on APPS.WF_USER_ROLES to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.WF_LOCAL_ROLES to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.WF_ALL_ROLES_VL to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.WF_ROLE_HIERARCHIES to ${new role}; 

grant select on APPS.FND_REQUEST_GROUP_UNITS to ${new role};
```

•As packages have invoker rights we are Performing the following:

```
grant execute on APPS.SP_XXX to ${new role};
```

Where xxx package is FND_USER_PKG, FND_RESPONSIBILITY_PKG, WF_LOCAL_SYNCH, FND_WEB_SEC, or FND_GLOBAL.

For example, grant execute on APPS.SP_FND_USER_PKG to ${new role};

3.Login by the new user name ${new user} and create the following synonym:

```
create synonym FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS for APPS.FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS; 

create synonym FND_USER for APPS.FND_USER; 

create synonym DBA_USERS for SYS.DBA_USERS; 

create synonym FND_RESPONSIBILITY_VL for APPS.FND_RESPONSIBILITY_VL; 

create synonym FND_APPLICATION_VL for APPS.FND_APPLICATION_VL; 

create synonym FND_DATA_GROUPS for APPS.FND_DATA_GROUPS; 

create synonym FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_ALL for APPS.FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_ALL; 

create synonym PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F for APPS.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F; 

create synonym RA_CUSTOMERS for APPS.RA_CUSTOMERS; 

create synonym FND_MENUS for APPS.FND_MENUS; 

create synonym FND_REQUEST_GROUPS for APPS.FND_REQUEST_GROUPS; 

create synonym FND_APPLICATION for APPS.FND_APPLICATION; 

create synonym FND_RESPONSIBILITY for APPS.FND_RESPONSIBILITY; 

create synonym FND_APPLICATION_TL for APPS.FND_APPLICATION_TL;

create or replace synonym FND_DATA_GROUP_UNITS for 
APPS.FND_DATA_GROUP_UNITS; 

create or replace synonym WF_USER_ROLES for APPS.WF_USER_ROLES; 

create or replace synonym WF_ROLES for APPS.WF_ROLES; 

create or replace synonym WF_LOCAL_ROLES for APPS.WF_LOCAL_ROLES; 

create or replace synonym WF_ROLE_HIERARCHIES for APPS.WF_ROLE_HIERARCHIES;

create or replace synonym WF_ALL_ROLES_VL for APPS.WF_ALL_ROLES_VL; 

create synonym FND_REQUEST_GROUP_UNITS for APPS.FND_REQUEST_GROUP_UNITS;
```

•As packages have invoker rights we are Performing the following

```
create or replace synonym xxx for APPS.SP_XXX;
```

Where xxx package is FND_USER_PKG, FND_RESPONSIBILITY_PKG, WF_LOCAL_SYNCH, FND_WEB_SEC, or FND_GLOBAL.

For example,

```
create or replace synonym FND_USER_PKG for APPS.SP_FND_USER_PKG;
```

Comment: Not mentioned the current version of the EBS, have you?

Comment: Current version of EBS is 12.2.7 .

Answer (score 0):

More efficient than creating additional synonyms for every user and EBS table you need to query, would be using the existing APPS synonyms instead.
This can be done by switching the default schema to APPS, e.g. with a logon trigger like this (replace username apps_query with your one)

```
create or replace trigger apps.apps_query_logon_trg
after logon on apps_query.schema
begin
  execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema=apps';
end;
/
```

Comment: Our requirement is to use the synonym for a user with limited permissions .Hence we cant switch the default schema to APPS.

Comment: did you try the solution I recommended? the permissions have nothing to do with the default schema. try it manually from sqlplus first when logged in as the user with limited permissions: alter session set current_schema=apps

Comment: Yes I have tried your recommended solution , it worked but it also gives complete access top the APPS schema for all the tables . I need to give specific set of permission for some tables not all , Hence I can not set the schema to APPS .

Comment: "gives complete access top the APPS schema..." no, it does not. if you have access to other tables than you expect, you granted more permissions than you think. try again with a newly created user and grant select on one single table only as a test

Comment: Thanks Andy , with this solution my issue got resolved as we no longer required synonym .  I am curios how much recommended this solution is as per security and access violation standards and what are the security concerns and impact we can expect .

Comment: There are no security implications as setting the current_schema doesn't give any additional access rights or grants. The users could also do this themselves after logon, if you didn't have it in the logon trigger.